# Adding values under same key HashMap in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I'm new to HashMaps, and I was wondering if there was a way to add values together if they have the same key.

For example, when I have the key 'a' and the value is 20 and later on I use the key 'a' again and the value is 10 the value should now be 30.

I don't know how I would check if the Value already is in the HashMap and then use the same value again. The adding part could be done with just a variable that copies the current value and adds the new one, I guess.

Comment: `HashMap#get()` method

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your question is actually three questions that you can search the answer to separately, that is 1) [check if a given key exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) in a map 2) if it does [extract it](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) 3) do your calculation and [put it back](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V))

Comment: Thank you guys and sorry I will check those links out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want a hashmap for character vs integer and want to add the integer to already present value in case the value is present.You can do something like below:

```
public hashMapImpl(char ch, int number){
    Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    if(map.containsKey(ch)){
        map.put(ch, map.get(ch)+number);
    }
    else{
        map.put(ch,number);
    }
}
```

Where ch will be your key and number will be something that you want to store at particular key.

Answer (score 0):

I will use an example class called `HashMapExamle` to explain this.
Inside the class I will create a `HashMap` called `bigHashMap` assuming that was your initial `hashMap` with prior data.

I also have a `main method` to call the method that will solve your problem. I have named the method `bigHashMap`. So for starters, i have initialized our prior `HashMap` named `bigHashMap` and initialized wit with some new `key-value` pairs.

I will printout the value of the HashMap. I will then add a value with the same key, in this case **food** with the value **15**, by calling the `hashMapValueAdd` method I have created and passing the key(food) and value(15) to it.

The concept of the method is:

1. Check if the HashMap contains the key.
2. if it has it, it will get the value with that ky and add the new value to it. it will then replace the value at the key with the new value.
3. If the key is not found in the `hashmap` then the new `key-value` pair will just be inserted.

```
class HashMapExample {

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> bigHashMap;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        bigHashMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Add test data
        bigHashMap.put("food", 200);
        bigHashMap.put("transport", 20);
        bigHashMap.put("entertainment", 40);

        System.out.println("Data before : \n" + bigHashMap);

        hashmapValueAdd("food", 15);

        System.out.println("Data after : \n" + bigHashMap);
    }

    private static void hashmapValueAdd(String key, int value) {

        // Check if hashMap contains the given key
        if (bigHashMap.containsKey(key)) {

            // Get previous value with the same key
            int valueWithSameKey = bigHashMap.get(key);

            // Increment the value with incoming value
            int newValue = valueWithSameKey + value;

            // Put updated value into HashMap
            // bigHashMap.put(key, +value);
            bigHashMap.replace(key, newValue);

        } else {

            // Put the current key since it does not exist in the HashMap
            bigHashMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

You can check out these `HashMap` explanations to get a better understanding.

1. [Java HashMap - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp)
2. [Java MAp - Jakob Jenkov](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-collections/map.html)
3. [Java HashMap replace()](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/library/hashmap/replace)
4. [Update the Value Associated With a Key in a HashMap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap-update-value-by-key)

Answer (score 0):

you can use compute method to add/sum a value in case a key exists, or create a new entry in case it doesn't.

```
Map<String, Integer> map =  new HashMap<>();

String myKey = "a";
Integer myValue = 10;

map.compute(myKey, (key, value) -> {
   if (value == null)
      return myValue;
   else
      return value + myValue;
   }
);

System.out.println(map);

map.compute(myKey, (key, value) -> {
   if (value == null)
      return myValue;
   else
      return value + myValue;
   }
);

System.out.println(map);
```

Outputs:

```
a={10}
a={20}
```

Of course, putting this *compute* logic inside a method will make you code cleaner :)